# Combining new lines and italics in facet labels with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a problem getting some words used in facet labels in italics. I use the following code to create new lines for the labels:

```
    levels(length_subject$CONSTRUCTION) <- 
c("THAT \n Extraposed", "THAT \n Post-predicate", "TO \n Extraposed \n for-subject", "TO \n Post-predicate \n for-subject", "THAT \n Extraposed \n that-omission", "THAT \n Post-predicate \n that-omission")
```

However, I want the words "that" and "for" to appear in italics. I've tried something like

```
"TO \n Extraposed \n (italics(for))-subject"
```

bit it doesn't work.

This is what the plots look like:

[image]

produced with the following code:

```
ggplot( length_subject, aes( x = SUBJECT ) ) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.6, colour="black", fill="grey") +
  ylab("Frequency") +  
  xlab("Subject length") +  
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(2,4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30)) + #
  facet_grid( SUBJECT_TYPE~CONSTRUCTION, scales="free_x", space="free") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8))
```

Here is a reduced variant of the data:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(1:86, .Label = c("A05_122_01", 
"A05_253_01", "A05_277_07", "A05_400_01", "A05_99_01", "A06_1076_01", 
"A06_1261_01", "A06_1283_01", "A06_1283_02", "A06_1317_01", "A06_1326_01", 
"A06_1389_01", "A06_1390_01", "A06_1437_01", "A06_1441_02", "A06_1441_03", 
"A06_1442_03", "A06_1456_01", "A06_1461_01", "A06_830_01", "A06_868_01", 
"A06_884_01", "A06_884_03", "A0K_1057_02", "A0K_1144_07", "A0K_1177_01", 
"A0K_1190_03", "A0K_1214_03", "A0K_1216_01", "A0K_950_02", "A0K_986_01", 
"A1A_102_02", "A1A_163_01", "A1A_199_01", "A1A_45_01", "A1A_97_01", 
"A1B_1008_02", "A1B_1013_01", "A1B_1028_02", "A1B_1042_01", "A1B_1064_01", 
"A1B_1126_03", "A1B_1152_01", "A1B_1174_01", "A1B_1271_01", "A1B_997_01", 
"A1J_487_01", "A1J_544_02", "A1J_555_03", "A1J_569_01", "A1J_601_01", 
"A1N_422_04", "A1N_70_02", "A1S_191_01", "A1S_329_01", "A1S_330_01", 
"A1S_465_04", "A1Y_248_01", "A1Y_278_02", "A1Y_292_01", "A1Y_466_01", 
"A1Y_521_01", "A1Y_612_01", "A1Y_634_01", "A26_139_03", "A26_142_01", 
"A26_148_01", "A26_289_01", "A26_345_02", "A26_439_01", "A26_441_02", 
"A26_463_01", "A28_171_01", "A28_244_01", "A28_245_01", "A28_30_01", 
"A28_341_01", "A28_42_01", "A28_494_03", "A2A_301_01", "A2A_396_01", 
"A2A_599_01", "A2A_637_01", "A2A_676_01", "A2E_22_01", "A2E_25_03"
), class = "factor"), SUBJECT = c(3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), 
    CONSTRUCTION = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("THAT_EXT", "THAT_EXT_NT", "THAT_POST", 
    "THAT_POST_NT", "TO_EXT_FOR", "TO_POST_FOR"), class = "factor"), 
    SUBJECT_TYPE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("NP", "PRO", "PROPER"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"SUBJECT", "CONSTRUCTION", "SUBJECT_TYPE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-86L))
```

Comment: A thought: try `labeller = label_parsed` inside `facet_grid`. Not sure what that will do to your new lines though.

Comment: @joran I the get the following error message: Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:3:5: unexpected '-'
2:  Extraposed 
3:  for-
      ^

Comment: @joran I will update the post to include a reproducible example.

Comment: you can't really mix `expression()` and newlines in R; the usual workaround is to use `atop`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get italics, you need the formatting described in `plotmath` (and then for that to be parsed as an expression). However, the `plotmath` syntax does not have a line break operation. You can get something similar with `atop`, though.  With your given example, you can set the labels to

```
levels(length_subject$CONSTRUCTION) <- 
  c("atop(textstyle('THAT'),textstyle('Extraposed'))", 
    "atop(textstyle('THAT'),textstyle('Post-predicate'))",
    "atop(atop(textstyle('TO'),textstyle('Extraposed')),italic('for')*textstyle('-subject'))",
    "atop(atop(textstyle('TO'),textstyle('Post-predicate')),italic('for')*textstyle('-subject'))",
    "atop(atop(textstyle('THAT'),textstyle('Extraposed')),italic('that')*textstyle('-omission'))",
    "atop(atop(textstyle('THAT'),textstyle('Post-predicate')),italic('that')*textstyle('-omission'))")
```

and then adding `labeller=label_parsed` to the `facet_grid` call

```
ggplot( length_subject, aes( x = SUBJECT ) ) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.6, colour="black", fill="grey") +
  ylab("Frequency") +  
  xlab("Subject length") +  
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(2,4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30)) + #
  facet_grid( SUBJECT_TYPE~CONSTRUCTION, scales="free_x", space="free", 
              labeller=label_parsed) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8))
```

gives

[image]

It's not perfect (the spacing between lines is not the same, and the disparity would only get worse the more lines there are), but that is the only way I've found to combine the two (newlines in plotmath expressions).

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice to find a way to fix the spacing though.

Answer (score 4):

*Edit (2016)*

With the new facet labelling system, this solution does not  work anymore. The trick of inheriting from `element_blank` to make a custom grob is [now explicitly disabled](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/864d64fa1d7a42a909df36fd5aea2c3e3610f25b/R/facet-labels.r#L527). I guess the lesson is to accept that some things cannot be done in ggplot2, [by design](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1240#issuecomment-127969165), and not waste too much energy with workarounds that may get broken at any time in the future.

---

*Original answer*

You could try to create a suitable custom `element` to place in the theme settings. The theme design does not make it very easy, unfortunately,

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra) # tableGrob

element_grob.element_custom <- function(element, label="", ...)  {

  mytheme <- ttheme_minimal(core = list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)))
  disect <- strsplit(label, "\\n")[[1]]

  g1 <- tableGrob(as.matrix(disect), theme=mytheme)
  # wrapping into a gTree only because grobHeight.gtable would be too tight
  # cf. absolute.units() squashing textGrobs
  gTree(children=gList(g1), height=sum(g1$heights), 
        cl = "custom_strip")
}

# gTrees don't know their size and ggplot would squash it, so give it room
grobHeight.custom_strip = heightDetails.custom_axis = function(x, ...)
  x$height
# silly wrapper to fool ggplot2's inheritance check...
facet_custom <- function(...){
  structure(
    list(...), # this ... information is not used, btw
    class = c("element_custom","element_blank", "element") # inheritance test workaround
  ) 

}


title <- c("First~line \n italic('wait, a second')", 
           "this~is~boring",
           "integral(f(x)*dx, a, b)")

iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species <- factor(iris$Species, labels=title)
ggplot(iris2, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line() + facet_grid(.~Species) +
  theme(strip.text.x = facet_custom())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As several of you were looking for how to fix the spacing, I have found a solution.
Add a line with `atop(scriptscriptstyle("")` before the last line from 3 lines (making this 4) or any following lines and don't forget to add `)` afterwards