# How to use italic in label_bquote for strip text lables

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, plotmath

There have been many proposed solutions to many slightly different problems, but none quite catches my specific problem.

What I want is the following: I want to mix normal subfig labels (a, b, c, ...) with species names in *italics*. So far, I only want do this for four species, so I could live with a manual solution. But a custom function automatizing the process would be neat...

E.g. the strip text of species a would be:

> > a)  *Genus species*

Here is a reproducible example with the `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(. ~ Species)
```

So I would like the strip text to read (ignoring the missing *Iris* for now...):

> a) *setosa*
>
> b) *versicolor*
>
> c) *virginica*

I tried to add the following modifications:

```
p + facet_grid(. ~ Species, labeller = label_bquote(cols = letters[1:4] ~ .(Species)))
p + facet_grid(. ~ Species, labeller = label_bquote(cols = letters[1:4] ~ italic(Species)))
p + facet_grid(. ~ Species, labeller = label_bquote(cols = letters[1:4] ~ .(italic(Species))))
```

Adding `letters[1:4]` obviously doesn't work. I also don't get, why `italic(Species)` would give me '*Species*' (meaning literally the word Species in italics) while `.(Species)` would actually paste the numerical levels of `Species` (1, 2, 3). And `.(italic(Species))` just gives me an error message saying `could not find function "italic"`.

How can I get **the levels** of Species pasted in **italics**? And how would I add then the letters to it?

#### EDIT:

I actually used the proposed solution by **Axeman**, that is `label_bquote(cols = .(letters[Species]) ~ italic(.(as.character(Species))))`

Here is the example again with the code that ran until recently:

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(. ~ Species, labeller = label_bquote(cols = .(letters[Species]) ~ italic(.(as.character(Species)))))
```

*However*, `ggplot2` or some other dependency seem to have changed so that this does not work anymore. Now it gives me the error `Error in letters[Species] : could not find function "["`. I have no clue why! Any idea?

Comment: You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037877/9022665

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Maybe I wasn't clear enought, I just want to have the species name in italics but the letter in front in normal font. If I set the face in theme, the whole strip text will be in italics...

Comment: Ok, then this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34980273/9022665

Comment: It would be `italic(.(as.character(Species))))`. Not sure about the letters. You might just have write out the factor levels and use `label_parsed`. E.g. use `iris$facet <- c('"a)" ~ italic(setosa)', '"b)" ~ italic(versicolor)', '"c)" ~ italic(virginica)')` and then `facet_grid(~ facet, labeller = label_parsed)`.

Comment: Actually, `label_bquote(cols = .(letters[Species]) ~ italic(.(as.character(Species))))` works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Axeman! If you post this as an answer I would accept it as such ;)

Comment: I still have a really hard time understanding the underlying principles of plotmath and especially the labeller function. I just don't get it...