# ggplot2 facet labels - second line is not displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-grid, ggtext

I have a script that used to produce a facetted plot with strip text on multiple lines. But this does not work anymore. Below is a MWE where the strip text should be parsed from, e.g. `"bold(A)\nreally~long~extra"` to:

> **A**
> really long extra

The second line is cut off as you can see via the debug function. I even increased the margins but to no avail...

Any ideas what is the issue?

```
exmpl = data.frame(a = 1:100,
               b = rep(1:5, 20),
               f = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 20))) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(f2 = paste0("bold(",f, ")\nreally~long~extra"))

ggplot(exmpl, aes(x = b, y = a)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ f2, labeller = label_parsed) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0, margin = margin(.5, 0, .5, 0, "cm"), debug = T))
```

[image]

#### EDIT:

And while we are at it, I only came up with this workaround because my previous solution of using `label_bquote()` does not work anymore. Please have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954819/how-to-use-italic-in-label-bquote-for-strip-text-lables), maybe you can help me with this, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure wether this works for you. But one way to achieve the desired result would be to make use of the `ggtext` package, which allows you to style your facet labels using HTML and CSS. To this end `ggtext` introduces a new theme element `element_markdown`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

exmpl = data.frame(a = 1:100,
                   b = rep(1:5, 20),
                   f = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 20))) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(f2 = paste0("<b>", f, "</b><br>", "really long extra"))


ggplot(exmpl, aes(x = b, y = a)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ f2) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(strip.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 10, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

And for the second question in your former post a solution might look like so:

```r
mylabel <- function(x) {
  mutate(x, Species = paste0(letters[Species], " <i>", Species, "</i>"))
}

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()

p + facet_grid(. ~ Species, labeller = mylabel) +
  theme(strip.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]