# Add subfigure number independent of strip text label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-grid

I would like to find an easy solution to numbering subfigures as this is a very standard exercise of my work. I could do this by arranging the plots and automatically adding number via e.g. `egg::ggarrange()`. However, this gets complicated and especially ugly if I have a ggplot that is already split into facets via `facet_grid()` and with a long strip text. I already asked a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710781/ggplot2-facet-labels-second-line-is-not-displayed).

In publications I would usually want to have subfigures with a label at the top left or right corner like `1, 2, 3...` or `A, B, C,...` and subfigure text label describing the facet centered on top. Both, the label and the text should be independent from each other. Looking at the solution of @stefan in my above mentioned [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710781/ggplot2-facet-labels-second-line-is-not-displayed), the labels and text are obviously not independent from each other and the labels are not left-aligned.

I wonder, is there maybe a function that puts labels like `1, 2, 3...` or `A, B, C,...` left-aligned on top of the top-right corner of the facet *independent* of the (centered) strip text itself? That would be awesome and would save me a lot of hassle.

I could obviously just use a label like `"<b>1</b> Text label"` and left align it. But this looks really ugly if I have a very long text. What I want to achieve is rather a numeric label on the left and a text label spanning two lines.

An acceptable solution would be to split the strip text into two columns that are independent from each other. This way I could put a number left-aligned and centered a text label over two lines.

Comment: Have you looked at [tagger](https://github.com/eliocamp/tagger)?

Comment: No I haven't! Thanks for the info, I will have a look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stefan I had a look at the [tagger](https://github.com/eliocamp/tagger) package. I find the `tag_facets()` function to be a bit hard to work with (especially the positioning).

However, I noticed that I already have the `tag_facet()` function (without the s!) from the `egg` package and decided to give it a try. This changes the margins of the plot in an unfortunate way and sets strip text to `element_blank()`, but this is pretty easy to revert ([similar solution presented here in the answer by @Lyngbakr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064042/using-facet-tags-and-strip-labels-together-in-ggplot2)).

I just add this to my plot and it works nicely:

```
egg::tag_facet(p, tag_pool = 1:5, open = "", close = "", vjust = -0.7) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(),
        legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0),
        legend.box.margin=margin(-10,-10,-10,-10))
```

(Although it would be more intuitive, this does not seem to work with the `egg::tag_facet_outside()` function though...)