# Cannot italicize facet labels with labeller = label_parsed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot

```
s = ggplot(final, aes(y = avg,x=factor(dose),fill = factor(mo))) + 
        facet_grid(.~gene, labeller = label_parsed) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", color = "black")
```

where final is a data.frame containing 4 columns: mo, dose, gene and avg.

I've been trying to italicize the facet labels with

```
s + theme(strip.text.x = element_text(face = "italic", size = 10, colour = "white"))
```

to no avail. Size and colour can be changed with no problems.

However, once I remove "labeller" argument from facet_grid(), the font face can be changed accordingly. Is this a bug?

Although I'll work around this problem by setting them individually as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16490888/5629703), I'm sure theme() was there for a very good reason.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible?

Comment: I'll give you an example label gene = c(alpha,a,beta,b)
the datapoints are not critical. simply spike in random numbers into avg

Comment: Useless now. Next time.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you need something like [what has been shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490331/combining-new-lines-and-italics-in-facet-labels-with-ggplot2)

In fact you **have** to change **directly** your levels  with `italic()`
then you use `labeller=label_parsed` in `ggplot`

an example:

```
factor1=rep(letters[1:3], each=3)
factor2=rep(1:3,times=3)
x=rep(1,9)
y=1:9
df=cbind.data.frame(factor1,factor2,x,y)
```

i revalue the levels:

```
levels(df$factor1)= c("a"=expression(paste("factor_", italic("a"))),
               "b"=expression(paste("factor_", italic("b"))),
               "c"=expression(paste("factor_", italic("c"))))
```

And adapt ggplot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=x))+facet_grid(factor2~factor1, labeller=label_parsed)+geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Tiny question.  What does cbind.data.frame() do that data.frame() does not do?

Comment: Thanks user. I want to italicize all the facet labels and thus using theme() would be the straightforward method.

Comment: @lawyeR from the help: alling this function is nearly equivalent to calling data.frame. [...]
This is a method for the generic function cbind. Calling cbind when at least one argument is a data frame is equivalent to calling data.frame with the same arguments, with the exception of the control arguments check.names and deparse.level.
Unlike data.frame, column names are not changed. If you want variable names to be made unique, call data.frame instead of cbind.

Comment: @J.lai: yes i understand. I have been looking for this some time ago, and i could not find anything else than to rename levels seperately. Sorry

Comment: @BerengereHusson. Nevertheless, your solution is less wordy than atop ^^. thanks a bunch!

Comment: @BerengereHusson. another thought just came to my mind. it could be that label_parsed overwrites theme() with respect to font face and there's no trivial solution if label_parsed must be used (in my case, greek symbols).

Comment: yes, i think so. Label_parsed is used to decrypt functions like expression(). so, somewhere, you have to "encrypt" your labels. But did you get what you needed when removing labeller and keeping the face parameter in theme?